# How to add npm user

Tags: windows, npm, puppet

I was trying to  add user using bamboo agent(user= bambooagent)and password(****) on windows using puppet.i'm getting error. can anyone help me in adding adduser with username and password in puppet exec resource.`enter code here`command => ${cmd} npm adduser --registry=http://absc.com

Comment: Please add the error and the complete puppet script you are using and the version of puppet you are using.

Comment: can you help me out with code to do manually on the cmdline which has username and password @RaviTezu

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `user` puppet resource to create a user:

```
user {'bambooagent':
    name            => 'bambooagent',
    ensure          => present,
    comment         => 'Bamboo Agent',
    groups          => ['<group-names-separated-by-commmas>'],
    auth_membership => inclusive,
    password        => '<your-password-here>',
}
```

More information here: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/resources_user_group_windows.html#local-usergroup-resources